# Does changing the target C standard achieve anything?

Tags: c, gcc, standards

I'm interested in the effects of compiling valid C99 code with a C11 compiler. Is there any practical difference?

As an example, could changing

```
gcc -c -pedantic -std=c99 source.c
```

to

```
gcc -c -pedantic -std=c11 source.c
```

achieve anything, where `source.c` is valid C99? Could this introduce regressions, or give optimisations for free?

I'm interested specifically in gcc, although answers addressing other compilers are most welcome.

---

I used the [C11 Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29) as a quick check to see the difference between C99 and C11.

I do notice that `gets` is removed in C11, so that's one possible regression. The only other one I can see is if the code does something like version detection that's not future-proof, like `#if __STDC_VERSION__ == 199901L` .

Comment: One of the ways can be to generate asm files and compare and then dig deeper.

Comment: I believe the valid c99 code shall compile the same in c11 mode (minus gets, of course).

Comment: @user58697 Removing `gets()` from the standard doesn't mean it is not allowed to support it, there is just no need. It is merely not required any longer. Compilers which support both C9x and C11 probably won't kick it out of the library.

Comment: @glglgl I don't have gcc at work so I can't try, but I think gcc has always warned about the use of `gets`. I think that maybe `-pedantic-errors` would actually error out if `-std=c11`.

Comment: @bubble Programming by experimentation with an implementation is not providing reliable answers, especially when the concern is about standard behavior--which is all about implementation-*independence*.

Comment: @Jens Agreed. I could compare generated assembly; but just because there's no difference in the asm generated by *my* files doesn't mean there aren't cases that I haven't covered.

Comment: @anthony-arnold I guess then the first thing you will have to do is let the SO community see the code. Which will be followed by iterating each line of your code against a list which contains all the differences between C99 and c11. Otherwise if you are asking for any general piece of code then it becomes such a broad question.

Comment: @glglgl: The fact that `gets()` has been removed means that `<stdio.h>` is not *allowed* to declare it. A strictly conforming C11 compiler may use the identifier `gets` for any purpose. The same program when compiled as C99 might be rejected because its own usage conflicts with the declaration in `<stdio.h>`. Also (not directly relevant to this question), this program `#include <stdio.h> int main(void) { char s[20]; gets(s); }` must trigger a diagnostic from a conforming C11 compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Backwards compatibility is considered very important for the committee that maintains the C standard.

You can expect that a strictly conforming program written according to the preceding standard will function identically when compiled with the settings for the new standard, unless

- the program uses a feature that was removed (`gets` when moving from C99 to C11)
- the program uses a feature that was made optional and is not provided by the compiler (e.g. complex types or VLA's)

The latter is unlikely to really hit you, because it is not expected that compilers that had these features will remove them now they are optional. It is more likely that if a compiler in C11 mode doesn't support VLA's, then it also doesn't do so in C99 mode (and will be non-conforming to C99 in that respect).

For programs that aren't strictly conforming (the majority of real programs), you also have to check that the new additions don't interfere with your code. Things to watch out for are:

- New standard headers that have the same name as your own headers
- Incorrect use of reserved identifiers that have been given a use in the new standard. In particular, identifiers that start with an underscore and a capital letter